# Object isn't found during repeat-loop but still appears in the global environment in R

Tags: r, repeat

I'm trying to remove an object after a repeat loop has finished but I get the warning message "In rm("games") : object 'games' not found". However, it is still in the global environment (which is why I want to remove it in the first place). Why does this happen and how can I remove "games" at the end of the loop?

```
games <- data.frame(wins=c(0,2),seconds=c(2,0))

foo <- function(n) {

  count <<- 0  
  repeat {    
    if (count == n) {
      rm("games")
      break
    }    
  count <<- count + 1
  cat("New count is",count,"\n")    
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading the help for `rm`, it only removes from the specified frame (in this case just the function environment), unless you tell it to go through all the parent frames using `inherits=TRUE`. So use:

rm("games",inherits=TRUE)

Note this is probably not very good style for a function to go deleting something outside its environment, but you probably have a very good reason...